# Eloquent Relationship in Laravel ManytoMany Through

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, relationship

I have three classes in my Laravel project : **City**, **Company** and **activity**. So, City has many Company, and Comapany belongs to a city; and then i have that Company may have one or many acitivities; What i'm asking about is how can I have all activities in a city.

City Model:

```
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Company');
    }
```

Company Model:

```
public function city()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\City');
    }

public function activities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Activity');
    }
```

Activity Model:

```
public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Company');
    }
```

Thanks for everything.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load city model with all companies and activities by using [nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
City::with('companies.activities')->find($cityId);
```

If you want to load just activities, you can use the [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method:

```
Activity::whereHas('companies', function($q) use($cityId) {
    $q->where('city_id', $cityId);
})->get();
```